# On a multiattack, if the first hit imposes a specific condition, is the second attack affected by that condition?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, conditions, multiattack

On a multiattack, if the first hit imposes a specific condition, does the second attack need to be adjusted based on the condition from the first?

For example:

A [Carrion Crawler](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/carrion-crawler) can make a multi-attack. The first attack is with its tentacles; on a hit, the target must make a Constitution saving throw or be poisoned for 1 minute. The target is paralysed until the poison ends.

On the next attack, the Carrion Crawler uses its bite. Does this bite auto-crit if the target is paralysed by the first attack?

I tried to keep the title as open as possible as I assume that if this is how multi-attack works it works for everyone and every condition this way. Please adjust if necessary.

Comment: Honestly, I think the title is too broad and sort of confusingly worded because it's so non-specific. What does it mean for an attack to be "adjusted"?

Comment: @V2Blast I think it's clear in that they are asking if any conditions/effects delivered by the first attack are taken into account for the 2nd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Yes, it is

Each attack resolves independently as it's a separate attack, with it's own roll. It's not a case of making one attack that hits three times.

Consider the [following clarification by 5e rules designer Jeremy Crawford](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2015/07/09/parallel-attacks-or-sequence/) regarding *eldritch blast*:

> Multiple attacks on the same turn aren't simultaneous, unless a
>   feature or spell says otherwise.

So if even the beams are not simultaneous, I cannot see how the attacks from a plain multiattack would be. In fact, if we look at the almost identical Extra Attack feature of player characters, it's mentioned in page 190 of the handbook that you move between the attacks; plenty of time for the paralyzation effect to set in.

As an additional note, an *eldritch blast* beam in combination with repelling blast, which pushes the target by 10ft, can [push a target outside the range of the other beams](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/616020559600599040?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw).

Unfortunately I couldn't find a direct reference to a monster's multiattack, but I believe that the way these similar cases are handled, in addition to the multiattack's text not saying anything about the attacks being simultaneous, is evidence enough that any effect from previous attacks should apply to the next.